# Could you help me to get rid of a white bar top at my WordPress site？

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Can you tell me what is the problem with this string, it caused a white bar top at my site, When I deleted this `e-con-full e-flex e-con e-parent` a part of the code or all the string as the string down below on inspect, then the white bar just gone, But I still don't know how to remove it permanently on the codes.

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-3431e35 e-con-full e-flex e-con e-parent" data-id="3431e35" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;content_width&quot;:&quot;full&quot;,&quot;container_type&quot;:&quot;flex&quot;}" data-core-v316-plus="true">
                </div>
```

[The photo of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amDyz.png)

[The element’s style document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvBaQ.png)

[Found out the exact style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs3UZ.png)

[Found out the source document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDC8g.png)

[Found out the exact code on the source document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juInx.png)

I want to get rid of it forever.

Comment: Have you tried: `.elementor-element-3431e35{display: none !important}` ?

Comment: Thank you so much!! Sir, I just applied it on the WordPress customizing additional CSS, it is working, and the white bar is gone, But can you explain a little bit to me about this code that I used, Is it just recovered on the old string or deleted the old string to instead of it?

Comment: You're very welcome. It's just a cosmetic fix, the div will still be there in the DOM, only it wouldn't be visible due to the CSS declaration.

Comment: @iorgv Is there any way to delete it with no more complexity?

Comment: Maybe a DELETE button, when selected, would do the trick.

Comment: I have tried to find `.elementor-element-3431e35{display: none !important}` this string on my Cpanel folder manager and the WordPress editor, but I couldn't find any like this string, because there are so many folders, and I don't know what exactly folder it is.

Comment: @iorgv where I can delete it?

Comment: (You might be able to delete it) in the Elementor's editor. But for that first you have to disable the CSS code that hides it.

Comment: Should I add a plugin to edit the css? In WordPress it‘s only has a theme file editor can edit some thing, but most of them are php files, is this string `elementor-element elementor-element-3431e35` part of the css? so I can't find out this string on the php files? because I have tried to find the string on some php files, but nothings show up. @iorgv

Comment: I believe that that segment of code (HTML) is part of your page, so you can edit the page via Elementor. I was referring to that if you want to edit the segment in question, you have to make it visible for you to see it in the editor. You don't have to add a plugin to edit CSS, what you did until now was okay.

Comment: But actually, all the things on my site are designed by Elementor free version without coding. So it's look like not code can be show up on any element, also the white bar can't be selected.

Comment: @iorgv I remember something happened before, I added a cart element on the top way of the site, then all of a sudden, the cart just disappeared, and left a white bar at the top.

Comment: Then, you should be able to somehow grab that element and delete it with a push of a delete button on the keyboard. One useful thing is the Navigator, which shows all the elements stacked on the page in question; you'll be able to see it there and delete it.

Comment: @iorgv I found out the element's styles on the [inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvBaQ.png), and I tried to disable these 3 styles, but there is nothing responded and the white bar is still here. Why? it's weird, why if I delete the element string directly it can remove the white bar, but if I disable the styles then it can‘t remove the white bar, Because what I thinking about now is the styles are related to the string, if I want to delete the string, I need to jump to the styles css exact document as the the photo show up that the exact style documents are in the styles back.

Comment: Sir, [I found out the exact style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs3UZ.png), [exact source document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDC8g.png), [and exact code on the source document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juInx.png), So can I finally delete this exact code from Cpanel file manager like delete the string that I high lighted on the,[exact code on the source document] photo.  Will it have any side effects or negative effects on my site after I delete it?
@iorgv

Comment: It would be better to delete it from the editor, not from the CSS itself. Haven't you found it in the editor (not the inspector) by checking it in the Navigator?

Comment: The white bar does not display in the Elementor Navigator, also the white bar can't be selected in the Elementor editor. @iorgv

Comment: Then only the CSS code to hide it remained.

Comment: Do you mean better to add this code `.elementor-element-3431e35{display: none !important}` in WordPress Customizing Additional CSS than delete it on CSS itself? So if I use the code to hide the white bar, will it cause any problems in the future while I continue to design my site? you don't want me to delete the CSS itself, because it will break out my site? so nobody edits their site on CSS itself? hope you don't mind I have a lot of questions, cause I don't know so much about programming. @iorgv

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant; add `.elementor-element-3431e35{display: none !important}`, it won't break your site in the future. And yes, deleting that part you found might break your site. Yes, usually both of the HTML and the CSS (and JavaScript) are present to edit one's site. And no problem, I'm glad to help if I can.

Comment: Thank you so much for teaching and helping me so much, you are a kind person, I think if edited on the site code, it needs to be exported the code and edited on the virtual environment outside of WordPress, but for me now, I want to reduce my work, so just hidden it right now, maybe in the short future I can afford to use some times to learn some basic coding and edit it, delete it on my site code, I am so happy to get your help, my friend. @iorgv

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad I could assist you, my friend.